# How to generate a list of random numbers with conditional statements

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, conditional

I want to generate a list of numbers with certain conditions.
Eg.
First I generated 10 random numbers between 1 and 20.
`M1= RandomReal[{1,20},10]`
Now I want to create a tabular list which contain numbers M1>9.
I have tried
`M1;While[M1>9];M1;`
But the condition doesn't work.

Comment: one way could be  `Select[M1, # > 9 &]`

Comment: Both the title and the first line of your question ask about generating random numbers with constraints, but then your example is about selecting points from a list and creating a *"tabular list"*. It seems the comments and other answers are focusing on the selection of items on a list after the creation of random numbers. Can you please elaborate more on what is precisely what you need?

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[1];
rlist = RandomReal[{1, 20}, 10];
```

> {16.5304, 3.11697, 16.001, 4.56826, 5.58586, 2.24904, 11.3027, 
> 5.39194, 8.52412, 14.309}

**Using `Select`**:

```
Select[rlist,  # > 9 &]
```

**Using `Pick`**:

```
Pick[rlist, # > 9 & /@ rlist]
```

**Using `RegionMember`**:

First define an implicit region (here you can also use `x > 9`)

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[9 < x <= 20, {x}]

Select[rlist, RegionMember[reg, {#}] &]
```

or use the operator form:

```
Select[RegionMember[reg, {#}] &][rlist]
```

---

Result:

> {16.5304, 16.001, 11.3027, 14.309}

---

Visualization:

```
NumberLinePlot[{Select[rlist,  # <= 9 &], Select[rlist,  # > 9 &]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One way *"to generate a list of numbers with certain conditions"* is to create an [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) based on your constraints, and then use [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) to sample points in that region.

```
RandomPoint[
    ImplicitRegion[1<x<20,x]
,10]
```

[image]